# Can't use preg_replace inside a static function, why?

Tags: php, preg-replace, static-methods

Is there any reason why I can't use preg_replace inside a static function? when I move the code out of it, it works perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: No, other than that you're not using it right. Can we see your code?

Comment: got any code to play around with?

Comment: @BoltClock +1. Had to laugh. @fast-dev: Our magic 8-ball is broken. Please provide code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny, because this works fine:

```
class obnoxiousWeasel {

  public static function callMeDoItIDareYa($omgudid)
  {
    return preg_replace("/(, you don\'t listen)/", '...',  $omgudid);
  }

}

$pieceofmymind = "ok, but what's the point, you don't listen";

$reply = obnoxiousWeasel::callMeDoItIDareYa($pieceofmymind);

echo $reply;
```

returns: "ok, but what's the point..."

We will need to see your code before we can tell you what is wrong. Using preg_replace inside a static function is definitely not the problem.

Edit: I actually edited the above useless function to improve it. Might as well face it, I'm addicted to refactoring.

Comment: +1 for for pointing out the obvious. Another (virtual) +1 for the identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace is a core php function and can be used at any scope.

perhaps you are using it to evaluate a class member in the static method?  that would not work.  but I couldn't say for sure without seeing a relevant chunk of code.